# iOS UITableView height issue when 3.5 inch simulator display

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

A `UIViewController`  with a navigation bar, a toolbar and a admob banner. Below is the code to calculate the height of the `UITableView` by removing the height of the admob banner, navigation bar and toolbar .

The `UITableview` height is OK if running on IPhone 5 and 4-inches simulator display. 
But if 3.5-inches and non-retina display, the bottom of the `UITableView` can not be scrolled to.

No matter the 4-inches, 3.5-inches, and non-retina display the height (self.view.bounds) is the same, 548. And the cell height is 41.

For 3.5-inches and non-retina display, if I minus 88(Navigation bar height and toolbar height) after removing the height of admob banner, navigation bar and toolbar height. Then the UITableView scrolls OK. But it not not OK for 4-inches display.

Any comment helps, thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{    
    // admob banner     
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];    
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;    
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];    

    // uitableview    
    CGRect rect = self.view.bounds;    
    rect.origin.y = bannerView_.frame.size.height;        
    rect.size.height = rect.size.height - bannerView_.frame.size.height
                                        - (self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height)
                                        - (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);

    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:rect style:UITableViewStylePlain];    
    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];    
}
```

Comment: How and where are you creating self.view?

Comment: Hi, alex you give me the idea. The UIViewController uses a XIB file. And its current size is 4-inches. Perhaps that's the reason why the view height is always 548, no matter of using 3.5 or 4 inched display.  After changing the "Size" to "None", the UITableView scroll is FINE, now. Thanks u all. I think it's the answer. But I can not mark your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adjusting your `UITableView` Autoresizing properties programmatically.

something like this

```
myTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

**update**

use this to determine your screen size and set your UITableView frame height programmatically.(Remember that you need to reduce(20) from the table view height because you have toolbar)

```
- (BOOL)hasFourInchDisplay {
    return ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0);
}
```

Comment: you need to set your table view frame height programmatically depending on which screen size your code is running.

Answer (score 0):

Is `self.view.bounds` changing appropriately on the different device?  If not, wherever you set the size of the overall view needs to change.

Also, most of this logic should be in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and not `viewDidLoad`, since views may be resized after they load.

Comment: Thanks, 1. If I move the code into viewWillLayoutSubviews, it still not works and the UITableView is even shorter (there is a gap between UITableView and the toolbar) then before. 2.  "self.view.bounds changing appropriately on the different device", I do not know what this means. Should I change it according to different display, for example 3.5 or 4 inches display ?

Comment: Your UIViewController (`self`) controls the size of the UIView (`self.view`), which is what you're inspecting here.  Its `height` and `width` are part of its `bounds`.  If its `height` isn't getting shorter on shorter iOS devices then your UITableView will always be the same height.

Comment: Can sometimes help ... in a somewhat similar situation, this saved the day .. -  (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews { // horrible fix, to make it position properly on all (most?? many??) devices! self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0); }

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
 rect.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - bannerView_.frame.size.height
                                        - (self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height)
                                        - (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)-20;
```

//20 for status bar

Comment: Thanks, but actually, it lacks of 88 if on 3.5-inches display. BTW, finally I know why. THANKS.

Comment: Hi, Jatin Thanks for your help. I think Alex's opinion helps me most. But Stackoverflow can not accept the comment as an answer. On the other hand, Priyatham51's answer also helps. Thus I accept it as the answer. BTW, thank you.